# 3 Same wifi SSID but 2 does not work

Tags: wireless-networking, ssid

I am having a problem connecting to specific wifi

The problem is that there is 3 wifi with same SSID

2 of them are not connecting to the internet

and the 3rd one is little bit far

The first and second have almost 100% signal always and the 3RD that i am trying to connect to have 80-90% signal

my device does not connect to the 3rd one it always choose the one with the 100% signal

what can i do ?

Comment: "my device does not connect to the 3rd one it always choose the one with the 100% signal" So your device uses either A or B so how did you conclude B and C internet isn't working?

Comment: @Ramhound There is 3 AP.. A and B with the highest signal are not working the router connect to them but i do not get an ip address.. The AP "C" with 80-90% work when i connect to it but i need to move around the router so it is also 100% signal.. AP "A AND B" 10 meter from me for example and AP "C" is 20 meter.. i am looking for a way to filter or to force connection to AP "C"... BTW i do not have access to the AP devices it is a public wifi

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your device will choose the best AP to connect on. 
You can have 3 different SSID and select them manually, or choose access point with user roaming capabilities.

Comment: i press on the 3rd one with 80-90% signal but it does not connect to it it go automatically to the 100% signal ssid, is there any way to bypass that ?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not an expert but I do believe that's normal.  I had two identical SSID's at my home.  I couldn't get my devices to connect to the second device unless I was on top of it because the signal strength on my first was much stronger in a broader area.  The device is responsible for determining what SSID to connect to when it's attached to multiple SSID's.

You can manually connect your device to the second SSID if you feel you need to but you'll have to micromanage it, because once you're out of range the device will switch back to the strongest connection.

Comment: the problem is the 2 other ssid with the strong signal does not have access to the internet only the 3rd far one

Comment: Are they intentionally made with no internet access?

Comment: It is a free public wifi the 2 strong access point always have problems

Comment: We're getting a little deep here but if you're connecting to 3 individual AP's with 3 individual networks conjoined, I'd suggest disconnecting from all 3 and connecting to the AP you want.  Now if you're connecting to a single SSID with 3 AP's, you're not going to be able to control that as easily from your device.  I'd recommend contacting someone to replace or disable the non-functioning AP's.

Comment: Every SSID have it own mac address, no way to filter or to force connection to specific mac address ? thank you

Comment: Right, each AP will have it's own MAC regardless of the configuration.  There may be software solutions for filtering AP connections from the client but I've never looked.  I'd rather just get the AP's functional or out of the equation entirely =)